# Debian installer doesn't display hard disk in partition menu

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I created a boot USB drive with Arch Linux and sucessfully installed it, but didn't like it as much as I thought I would so I then created a boot USB drive with Debian. The problem is that only the 16GB USB drive is visible in the partition menu during the Debian installation sequence and I would like to install it to the laptop's hard disk. I tried clearing the existing Arch Linux paritions from the disk by re-creating the Arch Linux boot USB and using the shell and parted to remove them, but this didn't make it visible to the Debian installer either. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a BIOS thing. Turn on USB legacy support or something along those lines.